# Django DRF Swagger: In urls.py SimpleRouter / DefaultRouter are not auto discovered by swagger docs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-swagger

Django DRF Swagger docs are not showing the ModelViewSets API endpoints registered as ROUTERS (not urlpattern).
In the example below standard docs (rest_framework.documentation) are showing/documenting this "follow_up" API and swagger docs are not, total skip nothing is showing.
For urlpatterns all is good, and below code for 'this_is_showing' is being nicely documented:

from urls.py file

```
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter, DefaultRouter
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view
from . import views

schema_view = get_swagger_view(title=MY APP API')

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register("follow_up", views.FollowUpViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^this_is_showing/$', views.SomeView.as_view(), name='view'),

url(r'docs/', include_docs_urls(
    title='API Docs', public=True)), 

url(r'^swag/', schema_view),

]
```

What am I missing?

django-rest-swagger==2.2.0,
djangorestframework==3.11.0

*EDIT 1*

django-rest-swagger Package not maintained anymore!

Moved to drf_yasg: great tool with swagger and reDocs inside.

Comment: which `django-swagger` version are you using?

Comment: django-rest-swagger==2.2.0 djangorestframework==3.11.0

Comment: On a lighter note `django-rest-swagger` is not being maintained anymore. If you still want to use it stick with `2.1.2` or use [drf-yasg](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg). I switched to `drf-yasg`, it is really easy to setup and for swagger it uses `2.1.2`.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm struggling with it too. `djangorestframework==3.12.2` and `drf-yasg==1.20.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DRF docs suggest that if you want to get the auto-generated API list view you need to use the DefaultRouter.  I wonder if the SimpleRouter lacks the introspective mechanism (or other hooks) that django-rest-swagger uses to get its information.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter

### EDIT 1

The DRF-swagger docs say that their example uses the DRF example: https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

The DRF example uses the default router: https://github.com/encode/rest-framework-tutorial/blob/master/snippets/urls.py

### EDIT 2

I believe you'll also need to include the router somewhere in your URL patterns.  If you look here: https://github.com/encode/rest-framework-tutorial/blob/master/snippets/urls.py

Not only is the DefaultRouter being used, but the router that's registered is included in the URL patters:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from snippets import views

# Create a router and register our viewsets with it.
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'snippets', views.SnippetViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

# The API URLs are now determined automatically by the router.
# Additionally, we include the login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Package is not maintained, so i'm moving to drf-yasg